# Why am I getting SQLSTATE [HY000] [1049] error when attempting to connect to a db that exists?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, pdo, database-connection

can anyone tell me why I'm getting `Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'api_db'`  error in my browser?  My DB credentials are correct and the DB does indeed exist.  I've tried changing my host to `localhost`  but if I do that, I get `Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

class Database { 

private $host = "127.0.01";
private $db_name = "api_db";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "root";
public $conn;

// get the database connection
public function getConnection(){

    $this->conn = null;

    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're root you should be able to connect to any database. Can you connect if you remove `;dbname...`? If so what does running `show databases` return?

Comment: @user3783243 if I delete `$db_name`, it works!  Where can I run `show databases`?

Comment: As a query with your connection. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php